# How I can remove shopware standard markup for using JSON+LD?

Tags: microdata, json-ld, google-rich-snippets, shopware, google-search-console

I use SW 5.10 and as see as following there is standard markup (microdata) as follows:

```
<meta itemprop="brand" content="xxxx"/>
<meta itemprop="name" content="xxxx® xxx xxx1.4 Caps (300 xxx)"/>
<meta itemprop="weight" content="0.41 kg"/>
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="buybox--inner">
```

I do a heavy search in SO and see json+ld is better for SEO and google so I decide to use a plugin for create json+ld and now is good as follows:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "Product",
"name": "xxxx 1.4 Cxxxaps (300 xxx)",
"image": xxxx.jpg",
"mpn": "93331FIT",
"brand": {
"@type": "Thing",
"name": "xxxxx"
```

now main problem is that both microdata and json ld structure is present for all products that with two reason this is not good choice:

1) I search in SO and found for one product this is not good to present both microdata and json ld.

2) json ld is better for google

so as a result I need to remove standard shopware 5 markup (microdata) to google search console not detects two same products on one page as follows:

[image]

> How I can remove this microdata for shopware to google search console
>   detect just json ld?

Comment: I don’t think it’s true that JSON-LD is better (than Microdata) for Google. Google recommends to use JSON-LD -- but from this recommendation doesn’t follow that you should go out of your way to remove Microdata and use JSON-LD instead; the recommendation is mostly for authors who don’t care which syntax to use (i.e., their CMS doesn’t publish structured data yet). So, unless a [reason for using JSON-LD](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/110150/17633) applies in your case, it’s perfectly fine to stick with Microdata.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overwrite every template file that includes the "old" syntax. This is nearly the complete detail page, since those rich snippets are included directly near their use.

e.g.:
https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.5/themes/Frontend/Bare/frontend/detail/content/header.tpl#L19

I don't think that there is any significant change in the seo performance of your site by changing this. And it could possibly break every template of plugins.

Comment: so you means if json ld and meta item both of them  being used this is not affect seo?

Comment: whole product micro-data not here in this file.

Comment: Sure, it is everywhere in the theme and you have to search for every single metadata. There is no central place inside the theme. I don't think that JSON-LD will provide you any significant seo boost.